# Configuring bash_profile to show git branch returns my branch twice

Tags: unix, git-branch, bash

```
# show git branch
function parse_git_branch {
  git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1)/'
}

function proml {
  local        BLUE="\[\033[0;34m\]"
  local         RED="\[\033[0;31m\]"
  local   LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local       GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local LIGHT_GREEN="\[\033[1;32m\]"
  local       WHITE="\[\033[1;37m\]"
  local  LIGHT_GRAY="\[\033[0;37m\]"
  case $TERM in
    xterm*)
    TITLEBAR='\[\033]0;\u@\h:\w\007\]'
    ;;
    *)
    TITLEBAR=""
    ;;
  esac

PS1="${TITLEBAR}\
$WHITE\w$GREEN\$(parse_git_branch)$BLUE\
$GREEN\$ "
PS2='> '
PS4='+ '
}
proml
```

The previous code returns the branch name three times. I just need to see it once...

```
~/projects/sms(apps2)$ 
(apps2)
(apps2)
```

How can I correct this to display just the path + branch?

ie .. `~/projects/sms(apps2)$`

Comment: Does changing last line to `PROMPT_COMMAND=proml` fixes anything for you? I have a similar script in my `~/.bashrc` and it works just fine.

Comment: yah that works. if you answer the question w that I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the last line of your script that messes up things. Calling `proml` directly from `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bashrc` sets `PS*` environment variables only once, so it won't be updated when you change folders (and you might have `(apps2)` displayed in every folder you enter later).

Instead, `proml` should be set as `PROMPT_COMMAND` in last line of your script:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=proml
```

`PROMPT_COMMAND` holds the name of the function to be executed each time before bash displays prompt. For more info see [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html).

Also, speaking of git-aware shell prompts, there's one nice addition to what you already have. Apart from current branch, you can get indication about any uncommitted changes. See e.g. [this blog post](http://intridea.com/2009/2/2/git-status-in-your-prompt?blog=company) for `parse_git_dirty()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Try changing the last line to `PROMPT_COMMAND=proml`

;-)